# Power bi - display total of count

Tags: sql, powerbi

I have a view that shows total emails sent per jobid.

E.g.

```
Select count(*)
...
Group by jobid
```

So results will be like...

```
Jobid 123 count 46533
```

In power bi I want to show a total of that count for the last week but e erg measure I try gives me bad figures...

Hoping someone can advise

Job Id       Total emails sent
161345      5000
161435      7000

In power bi I want to display this as 12000 emails sent

Comment: Please show us some sample data: the data, expected value, actual value, etc.

Comment: Edited question with example

Comment: @MatthewStott To be able to do this you should have some date column for when the email has been sent.

Comment: Sorry yes, the jobid field is linked to a job table in power bi that holds the email sent date

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to remove `jobid` from the group by and use a date on the view instead.

```
SELECT COUNT('8')
FROM ... 
WHERE [email_send_date] > DATEADD(week,-1,GETDATE())
```

I hardcoded the value for 7 days ago. There are more elegant ways to do this, but I would like to see what date format we are using on the view.

Can you provide sample data?